# bcrypt compare Hashed password resulting in Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'charAt')

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am trying to allow an existing user to signin, however I am getting an error in my Header component saying: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'charAt')`

I have the following code for my signup flow:

```
router.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
    const password = res.req.body.password; 
    const confirmPassword = res.req.body.confirmPassword;
    const email = res.req.body.email;   
    const firstName = res.req.body.firstName; 
    const lastName = res.req.body.lastName;  


    User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then(user => {
    
        if(user) {
            return res.status(400).json({ email: "email already exists" }); 
        } else if(password != confirmPassword){
            return res.status(400).json({ message: "Password don't match."});
        } else {

        const token = jwt.sign({ email: email, id: res.req.body._id}, 'test', { expiresIn: "1h" }); 
        const newUser = new User({ name: firstName + " " + lastName, email: email, password: password, token: token}); 
        const result = newUser;

            bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
                bcrypt.hash(password, salt, (err, hash) => {
                    if (err) throw err; 
                    result.password = hash; 
                    result
                        .save()
                        .then(user => res.json(user))
                        .catch(err => console.log(err)); 
                }); 
            }); 
        res.status(200).json({ result, token }); 
        }
    }); 
});
```

For my `/signin` route I have the following:

```
router.post("/signin", (req, res) => {
    const password = res.req.body.password;  
    
    User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then(user => {
        const result = user; 

        if(!result) {
            return res.status(404).json({ email: "email does not exist." }); 
        }
        bcrypt.compare(password, result.password, function(err, result) {
            if (!result) { 
                return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid credentials" });  
            } else {
                const token = jwt.sign({ email: result.email, id: result._id }, secret, { expiresIn: "1h" }); 
                return res.status(200).json({ result, token })
            }
        })
    }); 
});
```

My `Header` component looks like this:

```
const Header = () => {
    const classes = useStyles(); 
    const [user, setUser] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'))); 
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const location = useLocation();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        const token = user?.token; 

        // JWT ...

        setUser(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile')))
    }, [location]); 

    const logout = () => {
        dispatch({ type: 'LOGOUT' });
    
        navigate('/');
    
        setUser(null);
      };

    return( 
        <AppBar>
            <Typography component={Link} to="/">VERSUS</Typography>
                <Toolbar>
                {user?.result ? (
          <div>
            <Typography>Hello {user?.result.given_name || user?.result.name}</Typography>
            <Avatar alt={user?.result.name} src={user?.result.imageUrl}>{user?.result.name.charAt(0)}</Avatar>
            <Button variant="contained" onClick={logout}>Logout</Button>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <Button component={Link} to="/auth" variant="contained" color="primary">Sign In</Button>
        )}
            </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
    ); 
}
```

It is throwing the errors correctly on signin when I use a non existent email and the wrong password. However, when I try to login with a previously created user it throws no errors, but the entire screen goes blank and I have to clear my cache and cookies and restart the app. Not sure what is going wrong.

I've tried a number of things in the auth route, which is where I'm setting the signin and signup routes. However, I have not tried anything in the Header component yet.

Answer (score -1):

When you want to get the body send from client, it should be `req.body`, not `res.req.body`

So your `/signin` route will be:

```
router.post("/signin", (req, res) => {
    const password = req.body.password;  
    // ...
})
```

And in `/signup` route:

```
router.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
    const password = req.body.password; 
    const confirmPassword = req.body.confirmPassword;
    const email = req.body.email;   
    const firstName = req.body.firstName; 
    const lastName = req.body.lastName;
    // ...
})
```

---

And the error you get: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'charAt')` probably occur in your Header component at:

```
<Avatar ...>{user?.result.name.charAt(0)}</Avatar>
```

You can add another optional chaining like this `user?.result.name?.charAt(0)` in case of `result` not having field `name` and result in get `chatAt(0)` of null. Check your `User` document model or `console.log(user.result)` to see the return from express

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the response! I ended up realigning some things and got it working, the req, res mishap is noted though. Thanks again!